# analytic function such that $f(5z)=f(z)$ on $C\setminus\{0\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f$ is analytic on $\Bbb{C}\setminus0$ and $f(5z)=f(z)$.  I want to show that $f$ is constant.  Indeed, let $0<r<|z|<s$.  Then $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n z^n $ on the annulus and our condition implies that $a_n 5^n = a_n$, hence all terms except for $a_0$ are zero.  Since $r,s$ are arbitrary, we can use the identity principle to say that $f$ is constant on $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Wondering if I missed anything.  Thanks

Comment: Why does this imply that $a_n5^n=a_n$?

Comment: Just pick some $z_0 \neq 0$ and expand around there to get the same result without needing the Laurent expansion.

Comment: @copper.hat that's a lot easier.  Thanks

Comment: @Jonah f(5z)=f(z)

Comment: @copper.hat how would I show that $a_n 5^n = a_n$ though?

Comment: The condition gives you that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}a_n5^n=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}a_n$. How do you conclude from this that $a_n5^n=a_n$?

Comment: I may have spoken too soon, sorry.

Comment: @Jonah The coefficients of a Laurent expansion are uniquely determined: if $f(z):=\sum_{n\in \Bbb{Z}}c_nz^n$ for all $z$ in an annulus $r_1<|z|<r_2$, then for all $n\in\Bbb{Z}$, we have that for $r\in (r_1,r_2)$, $c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,dz$. Thus, if $f$ vanishes on the annulus, then each $c_n=0$ (btw to OP, this shows you do not have to appeal to the identity principle, it's just because of the uniqueness of Laurent expansions). Applying this reasoning to $f(5z)-f(z)$ shows that $a_n5^n=a_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative argument: Let $M$ be the maximum of $|f(z)|$ on $\{z: \frac 1 5\leq |z| \leq \frac 2 5\}$. Then $M$ is also the maximum on $\{z: \frac 1 {5^{n+1}}\leq |z| \leq \frac 2 {5^{n}}\}$ for any $n$. Conclude that $f$ is bounded around $0$ so it extends to an entire function. Now $f(z)=f(\frac z {5^{n}}) \to f(0)$ for any $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are meromorphic functions that satisfy this relation. (Consider $z \mapsto f(e^z)$ to translate this to a doubly periodic function.) So any argument using a Laurent series must at least take some domain of convergence into account.

An easier way to conclude that $f$ is constant is to note that $f$ is bounded on $A=\{z \mid 1\leq \lvert z \rvert \leq 5\}$ and since the sets $5^m A$ for $m \in \mathbb Z$ cover $\mathbb C^{\ast}$, $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb C^{\ast}$. By Riemann’s extension theorem, $f$ extends to a bounded entire function.

Comment: Doesn't f analytic on an annulus imply  that f has a Laurent series expansion on that annulus?  I'm pretty sure you can use the cauchy formula for an annulus to show this.

Comment: Yes of course it has a Laurent series. But it will need more careful considerations, since there are non-constant meromorphic functions that satisfy the functional equation, and these meromorphic functions also have a Laurent series on annuli that avoid poles.